# Pass a String to a Command that is Expecting a File

Tags: bash

I have a command line program that is expecting to be passed a configuration file e.g.

```
sphinx --config /some/config_file
```

I'm calling this command from inside a Ruby program where I'm currently dynamically generating the config file before writing it to disk.  This seems like a waste as the file is only used once and deleted right after.

Is there a way to avoid writing the file to disk by just passing in something that the program will think is a file but really hasn't been written to disk?

Comment: Look at /dev/stdout and /dev/stdin there may be a way to redirect output to stdout and read it inside ruby. Just an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a FD node and then have Ruby communicate using that FD on the process.

```
sphinx --config /dev/fd/10
```